# How can I read documents from other iOS apps?

Tags: iphone, file-sharing

I have an app which is similar to an FTP client. I can download various types of documents in it. (DOC, XLS, PDF, PPT etc)

Now, I want to read those documents in another application. For example: Suppose I download a PDF in my app, it is possible to read from AirSharing or File Magnet?

Comment: I will try to make clear now. I could download the pdf from one application. I want to read those pdf from my other apps in the iPhone/iPad. is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible for other applications to access Library folders owned by other apps, and definitely not private application folders.

[Document handling](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html) might handle what you want only to an extent - not the files that don't have their types registered to any app, and only at a one by one file basis, essentially duplicating the files as well.

If this is your app you are talking about, you can implement the Open In feature which is part of the [Document Interaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIDocumentInteractionController) in iOS, which will allow the user to access the file in any app that is registered to handle the extension/UTI.

In particular, these methods:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController  
– presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated: 
– presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:
```