# How can I read documents in my app's Document directory from other iOS apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an app in which i am downloading pdf files from server and store them locally in document directory. Now, i want to read that files outside my app , means i want to read that files using other pdf reader applications,

**How can I Read those files using other apps?**

I came across same question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201407/how-can-i-read-documents-from-other-ios-apps/%22Here%22),
it has good answer but it is too old. at that time it was not possible so is that possible right now?

**Is it possible to save those files in iBooks?**

**I want to make one thing clear**

> "I don't want to open the app supporting pdf files, 
>       i just want to open pdf files stored within my app 
>       with other app. like we can access Photos app & get
>       images from device like that i want to open pdf files 
>       stored within my app"

Comment: check if any PDF reader app offers such communication using URL schemes. Though just to be specific, which "other" app are you trying to use to open your pdf docs? But bear in mind, in the end it depends on others apps which may or may not allow such a thing

Comment: @NSNoob : "other app" means any such app that can read PDF files.

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma : I know i can read pdf inside my app and i have implement that too, but still i want other app can read this files too.

Comment: Yes which Apps exactly? Every App will have its different URL Schemes. Be specific.

Comment: @NSNoob : I already told you that any such app installed on device that can able to read pdf file. any means any, there is no specific app that i am looking for. thanks

Comment: this is not possible... because to open an app you have to know that app's URL Scheme.. then only you can open that app with your pdf... and in your case this is not possible... NSNoob is right

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma: don't want to open that app, i just want to open pdf files stored within my app with other app. like we can access Photos app & get images from device like that i want to open pdf files stored within my app

Answer (score 0):

You can open file URLs with UIApplication's openURL: method. Because of sandboxing, other apps could not access any files within your application's Documents folder.

You need to use UIDocumentInteractionController to open documents that you download or create in other applications.